# What's the way to change state when scroll passes element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to change state, when scroll passes my element. At this moment it works a bit weird. Namely, it changes state at the bottom of element. Why is that?

```
useEffect(() => {
   const handleScroll = () => {
        if(window.document.documentElement.scrollTop >= about.current.offsetTop && window.document.documentElement.scrollTop < contact.current.offsetTop) {
            setActiveNav(2);
        } else if(window.document.documentElement.scrollTop >= contact.current.offsetTop) {
            setActiveNav(3);
        } else {
            setActiveNav(1);
        }
   };
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [Intersection Observer (IO)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), this was created to solve problems like yours.

First you have to define the options on when you want to trigger your IO:

```
var options = {
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 1.0
}

var observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
```

Here we say trigger the `callback` when an element is 100% visible. 
Then we have to give it some elements to watch:

```
var target = document.querySelector('.about');
observer.observe(target);
```

and finally we define what should happen once the element is becoming visible:

```
var callback = function(entries, observer) { 
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    // Each entry describes an intersection change for one observed
  });
};
```

You can do stuff like [highlight the current section of a navigation](https://codepen.io/mishunov/pen/opeRdL)

There even is a [polyfill for supporting older browsers.](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver)